# JavaScript function is not working as per requirement

Tags: javascript

As per learn and try I am working on very simple function to understand features of JavaScript function. But after create function I am getting some issues, I hope someone can help me for my following questions.

Questions are:-

a) Why console.log from browser is showing ReferenceError: c is not defined ?

b) Why p id="demo" is not able to show result ?

c) Why alert(c); outside of the function is not showing result once browser load/refresh?

d ) Why return(c); is not working?

```js
function show(a, b){
  
  var c = a+b;
  alert(c);
  console.log(c);
  return(c);
  
}
alert(c);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;
```

```html
<p onclick="show(10, 20)" >This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You should not get that reference error from the `console.log` line, but from the second alert statement.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with refreshing.

Comment: If you define c in function is only define in function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572 gives the answer to your last question. Also, there is no `c`; where should it come from, your function has not even been executed yet?

Answer (score 2):

Because function braces in javascript define `scope` and all variables declared inside it aren't visible outside of it.
So `c` is undefined where you're alerting it.

```
function show(a, b){
   var c;
   //'c' is visible only in the function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i say in my comment :

If you define c in function is only define in function

You can do this :

HTML

```
<p onclick="show(10, 20)" >This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS

```
    function show(a, b){

      var c = a+b;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable c is local to function show. So when you call it outside of the funciton,

you get the error ReferenceError: c is not defined
and as c is nothing, p demo doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function show(a, b){
      
      var c = a+b;
      return(c);
      
    }
    var d = show(10,20);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
    <p onclick="show(10, 20)" >This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. can you please help me to learn more about return()?

Comment: return is a statetement, when executed returns from the current function. The lines after that are never executed. And we can return values in the return statement. We can return both data/function in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```js
        var c = "10";
        function show(a, b){
  
            c = a+b;
            alert(c);
            console.log(c);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;  
        }       
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;
        };
```

```html
<p onclick="show(10, 20)">This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```